# How to import SlidingMenu on my project with ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I found `https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu` very interesting and I want to use it on my existing project with actionbarsherlock 4.2. I have imported the library of the slidingmenu as an existing project of android. Then i went to the properties of my project and added the slidingmenu project as a library but I'm getting an error on SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);. There is also a red "!" on my project's folder.

[image]

[image]

I'm new on the sliding menu and i want a help. thank you very much.

UPDATE: I have fixed the most errors but I'm having this one which I don't know how to solve it
[image]

The latest errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field  CustomViewAbove.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 659    Java Problem

ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field  CustomViewAbove.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 660    Java Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').  
list.xml    /SlidingMenuActivity/res/layout line 2  Android AAPT Problem

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').  shadow.xml  /SlidingMenuActivity/res/layout line 2  Android AAPT Problem

error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').   list.xml    /SlidingMenuActivity/res/layout line 2  Android AAPT Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 11 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 20 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 30 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 39 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 50 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 75 Java Problem

MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 149    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivityHelper.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 87 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingActivityHelper.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 87 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingListActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 72 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingListActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 72 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingListActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 95 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingListActivity.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 95 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 67 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 67 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 90 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 90 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 195    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 195    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 198    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 198    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 298    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingMenu.java    
/SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 298    Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingPreferenceActivity.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingPreferenceActivity.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 68 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingPreferenceActivity.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

MATCH_PARENT cannot be resolved or is not a field   SlidingPreferenceActivity.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 91 Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 859    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 878    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 883    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingActivityHelper.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 46 Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 222    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 224    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 226    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 232    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 238    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 241    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 242    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 251    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 253    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 257    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 259    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 261    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 263    Java Problem

R cannot be resolved to a variable  SlidingMenu.java    /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib    line 265    Java Problem

The constructor SlidingActivityHelper(SlidingMapActivity) is undefined  SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 21 Java 
Problem

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/g3o/Documents/workspace/SlidingMenu/library/bin/slidingmenuactivity.jar'   Waiter      
Build path  Build Path Problem

The import com.google cannot be resolved    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 8  Java Problem

The import com.slidingmenu.lib.R cannot be resolved SlidingActivityHelper.java  /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 12 Java Problem

The method findViewById(int) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method   SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 38 Java Problem

The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type SlidingMapActivity SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 59 Java Problem

The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type SlidingMapActivity SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 83 Java Problem

The method onCreate(Bundle) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 19 Java Problem

The method onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method  SlidingMapActivity.java 

/SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 146    Java Problem

The method onPostCreate(Bundle) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method    SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 29 Java Problem

The method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method SlidingMapActivity.java 

/SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 49 Java Problem

The method setContentView(int) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method SlidingMapActivity.java /SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 58 Java Problem

The method setContentView(View, ViewGroup.LayoutParams) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method    SlidingMapActivity.java 

/SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 74 Java Problem

The method setContentView(View) of type SlidingMapActivity must override or implement a supertype method    SlidingMapActivity.java 

/SlidingMenuActivity/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 66 Java Problem

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    Waiter      Unknown Java Problem
```

---

**Solved**
I have changed the Goole API on both ActionBarSherlock, Slidemenu and on my project and all the errors disappeared

Comment: Did you import SlidingMenu? What error?

Comment: Where to import? I have imported on the eclipse

Comment: Please post your relevant code. I would like to see the class definition, where you are trying to create the SlidingMenu object, and the errors in Eclipse's `Problems` window.

Comment: i have added an image with the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend a SlidingMenu class. To *also* use the ActionBar Sherlock library you must follow the steps listed in the [Readme](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#setup), in particular this one:

> - Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend Sherlock__*Activity instead of _*_Activity.

So your project should extend SlidingActivity:

```
public class Waiter extends SlidingActivity {
```

And you need to change your copy of the SlidingMenu library to use ABS. Open `com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingActivity.java` and change:

```
public class SlidingActivity extends Activity implements SlidingActivityBase {
```

to:

```
public class SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {
//             Add "Sherlock" here:  ^^^^^^^^
```

(Repeat this step for any other SlidingMenu Activities you wish to use.)

Comment: so i have to extend my waiter app with sliding and then the sliding to extend the sherlock?

Comment: I solve the problem but now I'm having another one. Please see the last image on my first post.

Comment: That means you still have a problem somewhere in your project, the `Problems` window will lead you right to it. Save you file to refresh the problems window, if you still need help cut & paste the information into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: I have changed the Goole API on both ActionBarSherlock, Slidemenu and on my project and all the errors disappeared

Comment: But which Google API did you choose in the end?! and which one was selected before?!

Comment: If it's still interesting for you, I experienced the same issue, I changed the Build Target of the Sliding Menu from Android 4.2.2. to Google Api Level 17, now the errors are gone.