# Android, SlidingPaneLayout and listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, slidingpanelayout

I'm using a `ListView` as a secondary view in my `SlidingPaneLayout`.The main view is a map fragment. The `ListView` acts as a menu. The problem is that `onItemClickedListener` never gets called on the ListView. Even the list row never gets highlighted on press. it seems that the ListView can't get the focus.

EDIT:
actually, `slidingPaneLayout.findFocus()` shows that android.widget.ListView.  still no luck on clicking the list items.

Here is my xml

```
<com.ziz.luke.custom_components.MySlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/slidingpanelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactsList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/noContacts" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</com.ziz.luke.custom_components.MySlidingPaneLayout>
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: paste the code where you set your listeners, if your list is getting focus -and- the view looks right, then the issue probably isn't in your layout xml.  Also, how do you show/hide `empty`?

Comment: That's what I did. same issue. and I guess it's something related to the SlidingPaneLayout itself.

Comment: can you post the java code as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer. I was using a subclass of `SlidingPaneLayout` in which I was overriding

```
onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0)
```

I was trying to do the following:

- open the slidingPaneLayout useing a button.
- close the slidingPaneLayout useing a button.
- close the slidingPaneLayout useing swiping.
- prevent the user from opening the slidingPaneLayout using swiping.

So, I created a boolean inside my subclass called shouldSwipe to be returned from the over-ridden method.

the implementation that caused the problem was :

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {

        return shouldSwipe;
    }
```

it caused the problem whenever (shouldSwipe = true) because it tells the system that the touch event already is consumed and prevents it from being propagated.

I solved that using this one:

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return shouldSwipe ?super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0):shouldSwipe;
    }
```

that's it.

Comment: hello, i am using slidingUpPanelLayout for my app. I have swipable view with in the panel. but i am not able to swipe it to vertically. Can you Please help me for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have just created an example project using SlidingPaneLayout.

I didn't use any map because there is not where the problem is, so I just refer the position of the map with a TextView. I did use a ListFragment that is working and receiving the click listeners. Please download the project from here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33565803/StackOverFlowExamples/SlidingPaneLayoutExample.zip

Let me know if you have any configuration problem and if it solves your problem ;)

(I am using actionBarSherlock just because I am used to, so you can remove it if you want)

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion but maybe using the NavigationDrawer for a Navigation List Drawer would be easier then reinventing the wheel.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using this powerful library to make a simple sliding bar :
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

and here is how you can import it and use it :
[Solved: how to import SlidingMenu on my project with ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106136/solved-how-to-import-slidingmenu-on-my-project-with-actionbarsherlock-4-2-0)